# Read unquoted value as string

Tags: jq

I have an out from a tool, which is almost json.

```json
  {"acquired": None,
   "avail": True,
   "cls": "NetworkService",
   "params": {"address": "192.168.7.193", "password": "root", "username": "root"}}
```

The problem is `None` and `True`, is there a possible way to tell jq to threat these as strings?

I could preprocess with `sed`, but it would break if suddenly a third value appeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) can help you.
But with [yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) you can transform the input if you parse it as YAML and convert it to JSON:

```bash
yq --input-format yaml --output-format json file.json
```

**Output**

```json
{
  "acquired": "None",
  "avail": true,
  "cls": "NetworkService",
  "params": {
    "address": "192.168.7.193",
    "password": "root",
    "username": "root"
  }
}
```

Comment: Cool I didn't actually see the input as valid yaml, actually not yaml at all. But this command makes jq and json unnecessary: "yq --input-format yaml '.params.address'"

Comment: JSON is a subset of YAML.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness, the [other](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info) implementation, [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq), which uses `jq` directly, can also read and convert your input in the same way:

```bash
yq . file.json
```

```json
{
  "acquired": "None",
  "avail": true,
  "cls": "NetworkService",
  "params": {
    "address": "192.168.7.193",
    "password": "root",
    "username": "root"
  }
}
```